# Text positioning when using both landscape and portrait images in a gallery

Tags: css

Using fullpage.js as a horizontal gallery I want to align a textbox (see picture) to each image in the gallery. The problem is the different image sizes, text wont stay in place when the browser window size changes.

[image: The problem]

HTML

```
<div class="gallery-item">

    <div class="gallery-item__textbox">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>

    <img class="gallery-item__image" src="image.png" alt="image">

</div>
```

CSS

```
.gallery-item {

    &__textbox {
        position: absolute;
        width: calc(100vw/2); // ?
        bottom: 20%;
    }

    &__image {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: auto;
        max-height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your html code

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao done

Comment: Solved it with `max-width` on `.gallery-item` and `width: 100%` on textbox container